# How to use a library in a single file C++ code?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, static-libraries

How can I use a library such as the GMP library in C++ in such a manner that the file can be compiled normally without having the person compiling to install the GMP themselves. This is for personal use(so no license issues etc.). I just want my client to be able to compile my C++ code which needs the GMP library. I tried using `g++ -E` option, and it kinda works, but the problem is that on top of it are included many files which are themselves part of the library(and not available without the lbrary). Also the linker needs the availability of the library even if I do do that successfully.

How do I copy the entire library per se, maintaining a single file of code, such that it compiles and doesn't cause problems. I'm quite sure it is doable, because copying some functions works like a charm, but I can't copy paste the 3000 line code manually, so how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I guess what you want is to have your source and the *entire* GMP library in *one* file? And you want to do that automated?
I think there is no standard way to do this. You *could* write a script in you favorite language (bash, python, etc) which traverses the GMP code tree, appending the files (first the header files, then the cpp files) to your file while ignoring all *local* `#include`-lines. And hope that there are not too many macros etc which rely on the folder structure to be intact.

However, you could (and probably should) just supply the library and a adequate Makefile with your source code. Then the client wouldn't need to install the GMP lib, but could unpack the archive and run `make`. If the constraint is to do this in *one* file, maybe it is wiser to change that constraint...

Comment: NO that is not doable. Expect that all that can be done is what I said. This solution cannot work due to certain reasons. Is there some way to compress the library into my code itself?

Comment: So, you really *have* to get your code and all the GMP code in *one* file?

Comment: Yes. There is no other option. I didn't expect it to be this tough.

Comment: I have already tried using your new method, that causes linker errors, specifically, I get something like this when compiling with `g++ -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++11`: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BHdR5M7d)

Comment: Did you also exclude `#define`s? And can you find the missing symbols in your file? e.g. `___gmpz_mod`?

Comment: Ran a search. Unable to find any of them.

Comment: There your problem you have - locate them (`gmpz_mod`) in the GMP source you must, and find what's missing you will.